# Is the word "insinuate" a synonym of "infiltrate"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I have a practice test for the 2016 AFOQT exam. One section is "Word Knowledge" wherein you're given a word in all caps, then you select the word with the most similar meaning from 4 choices.

I purchased a practice guide where one of the practice questions is as follows:

> ```
> INSINUATE
> A. infiltrate
> B. introduce
> C. proclaim
> D. abbreviate
> ```

I didn't see a good answer, but I put "C". Their answer key has the answer as "A".

There is no published Erratum, so I want to make sure that defensiveness of my answer is not clouding my judgement.

The definition I have for "insinuate" is:

> : to say (something, especially something bad or insulting) in an
>   indirect way

The definition I have for "infiltrate" is:

> : to cause (someone) to secretly enter or join a group, organization,
>   etc.

Comment: [*Insinuate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insinuate) has two meanings. Not all dictionaries list both.

Comment: @Mick Thanks. Yes I finally saw that other definition when editing the question, but figured I would go ahead and leave the question as it may help some future reader.

Comment: Of those 4, 'infiltrate' is the only one with the connotation of indirect or secretive, which is also part of 'insinuate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/insinuate) lists the second meaning as:

> Manoeuvre oneself into (a favourable position) by subtle manipulation.
>   ‘he insinuated himself into the king's confidence’

It also lists "infiltrate" as a synonym.

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this as the answer when enough time has gone by.